# How to use the {app} path name in Inno Setup UninstalledAll message?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I see how to use the macro `[name]` or `[ver]` in a message in Inno Setup. Is there any way to use the application path (specified elsewhere in Inno Setup by `{app}`)? When I uninstall my app, I want to tell the user that a file still exists on the disk with the pathname of the app and that there's an environmental variable that contains it. I don't want to delete the file with the pathname and I don't want to clear the variable, because they might have other paths in them, but I do want to warn the user.

This is the Inno Setup entry I'm trying to fix:

```
[Messages]
UninstalledAll=%1 uninstall complete.%n%nI did not try to remove the APP-PATHNAME-HERE from the PATH16 environment variable, or from the PATH statement in autoexec.bat in your otvdm\C folder. You may safely ignore these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a *custom message*. That's a standard message. You cannot modify standard messages this way.

All you can do is to display yet another message. For example from [`CurUninstallStepChanged(usPostUninstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurUninstallStepChanged).

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  Message: string;
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usPostUninstall then
  begin
    Message :=
      Format(
        'I did not try to remove the %s from the PATH16 environment variable, ' +
        'or from the PATH statement in autoexec.bat in your otvdm\C folder. ' +
        'You may safely ignore these.', [ExpandConstant('{app}')]);
    MsgBox(Message, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!